# Запись словаря в Excel файл (.xlsx)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Пытаюсь записать словарь в excel файл. И сразу же возникают проблемы, как указать на то, что в шапке нужно использовать ключи? Ведь словарь неупорядочен и по сути данные могут записаться в произвольном порядке, если словарь создавался где-то извне?

Или может нужно как-то это делать при помощи `pandas`?

```
import openpyxl


if __name__ == '__main__':

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()

    test_dict = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3]}

    for columnnum in range(len(test_dict)):
        for rownum in range(len(list(test_dict.values())[0])):
            sheet.cell(row=rownum+2, column=columnnum+1).value = list(test_dict.values())[columnnum][rownum]
    wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

P.S. Есть ли возможность записать данные с пропуском строки, например:

строка 1 - `a`, `b`

строка 2 - `test_dict['a'][0]`, `test_dict['b'][0]`

cтрока 3 - пусто

строка 4 - `test_dict['a'][1]`, `test_dict['b'][1]`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd

test_dict = {'b': [2, 3], 'a': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict).sort_index(axis=1)

# insert an empty string at position [n]
n = 1
res = pd.concat([df.iloc[:n],
                 pd.DataFrame([[""]*len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns),
                 df.iloc[n:] 
                ], 
                ignore_index=True)

res.to_excel("sample.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]